# GitHub usernames "can't end with a hyphen"... but mine does

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

I'm trying to add a project from GitHub to my Developer Story using the GH import tool. This has worked before - one of the projects already on my story was imported with this tool. However, this time it's telling me that GitHub usernames can't start or end with a hyphen:

[image]

As you can see... [mine does](https://github.com/ArtOfCode-).

Comment: You broke GitHub and now you complain here ... ;)

Comment: Looks like GitHub used to allow usernames ending with a hyphen [but now doesn't anymore](https://github.com/shinnn/github-username-regex/issues/1).

Comment: So instead of using the same restrictions as GitHub currently uses, SO should simply check whether the username exists (e.g. check that `https://api.github.com/users/:username` returns a non-error response).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has been fixed and should be up with our next prod build. There was no reason for us to run GitHub user name validations on our end, so we're no longer doing that. Thanks for your report